# In Sails 0.12 blueprint, what controller action is triggered when you call upon a nested route in one-to-many?

Tags: sails.js

Say you have a one-to-many relationship between Person and Pet: a person has many pets. After establishing that relationship in Sails, we get the following default restful route from the blueprint API:

```
GET /person/:personId
```

The route above maps to the `PersonController.findOne` action. Now, what I want to know is, where does the following route map to? What controller action?

```
GET /person/:personId/pet
```

(Gets all the pets for a specific person)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an association where the person has many pets, the route

```
GET /person/:personId/pet
```

matches the `PersonController.populate` action.

In general,

```
GET /resource/:resourceId/:association
```

Will populate the field determined by the `:association` parameter, which calls upon the `populate` action in the controller.

Ref: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/populate-where